# Creating table with crossing arrows in latex

Tags: tables, pdftex

I want to have a table having the format indicated in the picture attached below using LaTeX. Any help is highly appreciated!

[image]

The following is what I've tried.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{c-rectangle2/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum
width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, text width = 5cm, draw=black,
fill=white},
arrow/.style={ultra thick,->,>=stealth}}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm]
    \node (start) [c-rectangle2] {zz + yy};
\node[below=1cm of start] (tabA){\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
A & B \\\hline
aa & 20\\
bb & 30\\
cc & 40\\
dd & 50\\\hline
\end{tabular}};
\draw[arrow] (start) -- (tabA);
\node[right=1cm of tabA] (tabB){\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
C \\ \hline
10\\
10\\
10\\
10\\\hline
\end{tabular}};
\node[right=1cm of tabB] (tabC){\begin{tabular}{|D|}
\hline
D \\ \hline
5\\
5\\
5\\
5\\\hline
\end{tabular}};
\node (box1) [c-rectangle2,below of=tabA, below=0.5cm] {
\begin{itemize}
    \item [$-$] a
    \item [$-$] b
\end{itemize}};
\node (box2) [c-rectangle2,right = 1cm of box1] {
\begin{itemize}
    \item [$-$] a
    \item [$-$] b
\end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to TeX-SE. I highly recommand using `tikz` in that matter. Did you try something yet? It would be nice to help you from something you already wrote.

Comment: I have no clue about tikz. I will put it in case I come up with something!

Comment: You also can see what can be done with `pstricks`,  more precisely with the `pst-node` package.

Comment: @SebGlav I included some codes. Would check it, please?